# GWT: handling more than one events on Label

Tags: gwt, event-handling, click, keydown

I want handle events on a Label when user holds down some key (Ctrl) and then clicks the mouse button together (Ctrl + mouse click), like open some window etc... 
How could i do that in GWT? Should i get add two handlers or can do it with one?

### thank you.

al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click handler you can check if the Ctrl key is pressed when the event was fired, see example below. You also might want to check for the specific mouse button the user clicked on. I've also added that to the example:

```
yourLabel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    if(NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT == event.getNativeButton() &&
        event.isControlKeyDown()) {
        //do what you want
    }
});
```

Or for older version of GWT instead of `event.isControlKeyDown` use `event.getNativeEvent().getCtrlKey()`, which returns a boolean value true if the control key is pressed when this event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: this code is buggy, please look at Hilbrand's answer**

To be honest, I don't think you can do it with 1 or 2 handlers. I think you would need 3 handler.

1. A KeyDownHandler that sets a boolean you can later read form the MouseDownHandler
2. A MouseDownHandler that does what you want
3. A KeyUpHandler that resets the value of the boolean in the KeyDownHandler

   ```
   boolean ctrlPressed;
   yourLabel.addDomHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
       public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
           if(event.getAssociatedType().equals(KeyCodes.KEY_CTRL))
               ctrlPressed=true;                   
       }
   }, KeyDownEvent.getType()); 

   yourLabel.addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
       public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
           if(event.getAssociatedType().equals(KeyCodes.KEY_CTRL))
               ctrlPressed=false;                  
           }
   }, KeyUpEvent.getType()); 

   yourLabel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
       if(ctrlPressed) {
           //do what you want
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: i guess this is a mistake on 2nd line? "yourLabel.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {"

Comment: Yes, tt was, sorry. Just delete that line. I have edited the answer.

Comment: btw, is possible with overriding the onBrowserEvent ? like get the Crtl key and setting the boolean and then on click, i do whatever i want to?

Comment: I havn't used onBrowserEvent, so I cant't answer that

Comment: I've down voted this answer, because the code in this answer is buggy! The problem is when the user pressed the Ctrl Key, Widget loses focus, then the keyup event will never fire and the widget remains in the state Ctrl key pressed. The next time a user clicks on this widget, without pressing the Ctrl key it will incorrectly run as if the Ctrl key was clicked, because it still has that state.

Comment: @ Hildebrand thanks a lot for the reply. I will debug it when I find the time, but I don't think you are correct that the widget loses focus if you press Ctrl. If this would happen you couldn't copy text into a textbox by ctrl + v.

Comment: @Chris. I wrote that down to fast:-). Your right the widget doesn't lose focus. What I intended to say was that in a use case where something will make the widget lose focus. This can be something simply as the user clicking on some other area in or outside the browser, or simply because the OS comes up with a popup.